# Match whitespace in Javascript regexp by object, created through RegExp constructor

Tags: javascript, regex

Please, look into this code. Why does creating of the same regular expression by different ways (by **/*regex*/** literal and through **RegExp** constructor) cause different result? Why doesn't the second pattern match the whitespace in the **str**?

```
var str = " "; 

var pat1 = /\s/;
document.writeln(pat1.test(str)); // shows "true"

var pat2 = new RegExp("\s");
document.writeln(pat2.test(str)); // shows "false"
```

Can't find the answer on my question anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash since it's in a string:

```
var pat2 = new RegExp("\\s");
```